# How to add custom parameters in GeoServer cascading WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

I want to add additional parameters (like time, layer_name) to my cascaded WMS which is using a Flask API (for converting vector data to raster) as source. The parameters can take dynamic value, so to make changes in capabilities doc ( [as mentioned here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379727/geoserver-wms-cascading-how-to-define-a-custom-parameter) ) won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the WMS cascading code.

Comment: I looked into the GeoServer and Geotools code and tried debugging WMSCoverageReader class in WMS getMap but was  unable to find the specific place where I can add these additional vendor parameters. Could you please let me know a little more on where to add these parameters in the code. I was unable to find any help from the GeoServer documentation.